# vue js fadein effect > can you make this code by js fadein (with vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fadein

```
    let fadeTarget = document.getElementById("detail-poster")
    let faedEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1
      } else {
        clearInterval(faedEffect)
      }
      this.num = (this.num + 1) % this.backDropImage?.backdrops.length
    }, 200)
  }
```

i find vanilla js fade out effect but there is no **fade in effect**
anybody know how make fade in effect with vanilla js??

Comment: Use [animate.css](https://animate.style/)

Answer (score 0):

You basically do the opposite of the fade out that you have above, but you start at zero and increment (instead of decrement) the opacity until it equals 1.

```js
let fadeTarget = document.getElementById("detail-poster")
    let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 0
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 1) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity += 0.1
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect)
      }
    }, 200)
```